# Unable to launch Chrome by Selenium using Python

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, webdriver

I was trying to open Chrome by Selenium using Python but getting error as "Data;" in address bar. After that I updated the Chrome driver version to 2.29 but now I am getting error as Google Chrome version should be >=56 and my version is 55.

I tried to update Google Chrome but I don't have administrator rights to update Google Chrome.

Comment: Although I have never tried this, you could try installing a local copy of chrome on your desktop and point selenium to that instance.

Comment: Download chrome driver v2.27 from here https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.27/

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use Chrome version 55, you will need to use a chromedriver in the range of versions 2.25-2.28. See the [release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.29/notes.txt) for version compatibility.